# How to find the current biweekly period in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, time

I want to run some Find statements that only show results from the current two week period of a company - it's the pay period for the company.  In other words, not necessarily just the last two weeks of records.  A quick search looks like I am not going to be able to use a built-in Time method like `Time.now.beginning_of_quarter` or `Time.now.end_of_quarter`.  What's the best way to implement this?

Comment: are you sure this is a Ruby-on-rails question? seems more like a SQL question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the `Date` class instead of `Time`, you could make use of the [`cweek`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/Date.html#M000175) method to get which week of the year a date falls into, and divide that by two to determine which biweekly period.

For instance:

```
now = Date.today #=> Thu, 10 Dec 2009
period = now.cweek / 2 #=> 25
```

Note that cweek takes the fact that the year doesn't divide equally into 52 weeks (and therefore not into 26 periods either).